# How to check if the height of one of the elements with class exceeds a threshold?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some sections that have a min-height of 100vh.

How do i setup an if statement that checks when óne of the elements exceeds the viewport height? Currently i have the following but that does not work for some reason:

```
var section = $('.fh-section');
var height = $(window).height();
   if (section.height() > height) {
      execute code
   }
```

I feel like it will only execute if all the elements with the .fw-section class exceed the height it results  true. How do i set it up so it results true if at least one of the elements exceeds the window height?

Comment: sorry, i knew that but messed it up apparently...

Comment: Don't worry. Lots of people don't!

Comment: well height() with a jQuery collection will only look at the first element so that code will only work if the first element is greater. If any others are, then it will not work. So you would need to loop over the collection and check each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all elements with the specified class like this:

```
var height = $(window).height();

$('.fh-section').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).height > height)
    {
        // CODE

        return false; // stops the loop
    }
});
```